# Unable to send keypress to Xvfb display using XTestFakeKeyEvent

Tags: c, x11, keyboard-events, xvfb, xinput

Using this short snippet of code I am able to capture events from the keyboard (/dev/input/event1) and print them properly. However, sending them to the Xvfb display using XTestFakeKeyEvent does not work even if XTestFakeKeyEvent returns successful.

```
char devname[] = "/dev/input/event1";
int device = open(devname, O_RDONLY);
struct input_event ev;
signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
if (!dpy) {fprintf(stderr, "unable to connect to display");return 7;}
while(1)
{
        read(device,&ev, sizeof(ev));
        printf("Key: %i State: %i\n",ev.code,ev.value);
        if(ev.code!=4)
                if(!(XTestFakeKeyEvent(dpy, ev.code, ev.value, 0)))
                        {fprintf(stderr, "unable to send keystroke\n");return 7;};
}
```

I thought the problem was with the compatibility between Xvfb and XTestFakeKeyEvent but I am able to send keystrokes to the display using the xdotool program in the shell, which uses XTestFakeKeyEvent. It's possible that I'm doing this wrong, I'm not familiar with X11 programming. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Xvfb and XTestFakeKeyEvent together and they're compatible.

You seem to be giving `ev.value` raw into `XTest`. `ev.value` is 1 for keydown and 0 for keyup. However XTest has these codes defined: ([source](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/xtest.html#New_Types))

```
FAKE_EVENT_TYPE
     2     KeyPress
     3     KeyRelease
     4     ButtonPress
     5     ButtonRelease
     6     MotionNotify
```

=> KeyPress needs to be 2 and release needs to be 3. Also I'm not sure about the function argument order, you should validate that too if it still doesn't work. :)

p.s. you might be interested to read https://joonas.fi/2020/12/attach-a-keyboard-to-a-docker-container/

Comment: OP uses `XTestFakeKeyEvent()` which takes bool as third parameter True for key press False for key release. source you sent is for x11 network protocol, which OP doesnt use directly.

Answer (score 0):

Most of X* functions are actually just writes itself to buffer. For send that buffer to your xserver you need to call `XFlush()` or other similar function.

So just call `XFlush()` after your `XTestFakeKeyEvent()`.

[manual page of XFlush](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XSync.3.html)

Check `open()` and `read()` return values for error check.

Be sure `ev.type` is key related by adding your code `if(ev.type != EV_KEY) continue;` after `read()`

`XTestFakeKeyEvent()` takes keycode but `ev.code` is probably scancode. You need to translate scancode into keycode to use it.

`ev.value` is also can give repeat value which is `2` but `XTestFakeKeyEvent()` doesn't have repeat so you can give `!!ev.value` to it.